# How to use regex function properly (regex not functioning properly)

Tags: r, string, vector, split, matching

This is an exercise i am doing and i am given the following instructions:

Come up with a strategy that splits punctuation marks or spaces, except that it keeps intact words like "I've" or "wasn't", that have a punctuation mark in the middle, in between two letters. (Or when the punctuation mark is at the beginning, as in "'em", or when there is a dollar sign at the beginning.) Apply your strategy to trump.words as defined below such that you display only those words with punctuation marks and/or dollar signs. The answer given to the exercise should be 102 [not necessarily unique, but total] words when using this strategy.

**My attempte line of code/input:**

```
trump.lines = readLines("http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~pfreeman/trump.txt")
my.pattern=("([a-z]|[A-Z]){0,}([[:punct:]]|$){1,}([[:alnum:]]{1,})")
exp=regexpr(my.pattern,trump.lines,useBytes=TRUE)
regmatches(trump.lines,exp)
```

The output:

```
 [1] "would've"          "carefully-crafted" "Administration's" 
 [4] "nation's"          ",000"              "border-crosser"   
 [7] "I've"              "African-American"  "$800"             
[10] "$19"               "$150"              "America's"        
[13] "Let's"             "Clinton's"         "nation's"         
[16] "Clinton's"         "won't"             "\"extremely"      
[19] "America's"         "we're"             "don't"            
[22] "there's"           "African-American"  "it's"             
[25] "America's"         "won't"             "It's"             
[28] "I'm"               "nearly-one"        "China's"          
[31] "it's"              "China's"           "we'll"            
[34] "Middle-income"     "highest-taxed"     "$2"               
[37] "that's"            "We're"             "ten-point"        
[40] "I'm"               "I'll"              "I'm"              
[43] "he'd"              "there's"           "It's"             
[46] "can't"             "don't"             "\"I"
```

One of the problems i found in my code is that there are six I'm in the original txt file while i only ouputted 3, I do not understand how that would be possible. ***Any help or general nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
grep("['$-]", unlist(strsplit(gsub(" -{1,2}", "", trump.lines), " ")), value = T)
```

Explanation:
Here; we're doing four opertaions in one go:

1. `gsub(" -{1,2}", "", trump.lines)` removes free-standing double or single dashes
2. `strsplit(gsub(" -{1,2}", "", trump.lines), " ")`splits the input received from the previous operation into 'words' based on the presence of whitespace
3. `unlist(strsplit(gsub(" -{1,2}", "", trump.lines), " "))`unlists the result of the two previous operations
4. `grep("['$-]", unlist(strsplit(gsub(" -{1,2}", "", trump.lines), " ")), value = T)`, finally, matches those 'words' that have at least one member from the character class `'` or `$` or `-` in them (as the 'words' that are preceded by `"` and/or `\`happen to have one of the three characters in the character class, these characters need not be mentioned explicitly)

Hope this helps.

Output:

```
 [1] "would've"          "would've"          "would've"          "carefully-crafted" "Administration's" 
 [6] "America's"         "That's"            "nation's"          "President's"       "border-crosser"   
[11] "years-old,"        "class'"            "I've"              "Sarah's"           "wasn't"           
[16] "African-American"  "African-American"  "$4,000"            "that's"            "$800"             
[21] "$800"              "We're"             "$19"               "forty-three"       "$150"             
[26] "America's"         "Let's"             "Let's"             "pre-Hillary,"      "Clinton's"        
[31] "America's"         "nation's"          "it's"              "Clinton's"         "laid-off"         
[36] "they're"           "won't"             "can't"             "America's"         "America's"        
[41] "It's"              "It's"              "It's"              "It's"              "nation-"          
[46] "we're"             "don't"             "there's"           "African-American"  "other-"           
[51] "it's"              "America's"         "catch-and-release" "won't"             "It's"             
[56] "I'm"               "nearly-one"        "China's"           "husband's"         "it's"             
[61] "China's"           "we'll"             "don't"             "Middle-income"     "highest-taxed"    
[66] "job-killers"       "$2"                "that's"            "she's"             "that's"           
[71] "she's"             "We're"             "ten-point"         "I'm"               "I'll"             
[76] "they've"           "I'm"               "I'm"               "he'd"              "It's"             
[81] "there's"           "'em"               "It's"              "don't"             "can't"            
[86] "wouldn't"          "doesn't"           "don't"             "Don't"             "don't"            
[91] "It's"              "three-word"        "\"I'm"             "\"I'm"
```

Comment: kind of and thank you, im asked to use less advanced methods (using [[:pucnt:]] etc) and i could not figure out where i went wrong; if you can please explain a bit on my code

Comment: Explain **your** code? I can only explain my code ...

Comment: sorry of course: "([a-z]|[A-Z]){0,}([[:punct:]]|$){1,}([[:alnum:]]{1,})" is any letter appearing 0 or more times followed by either punctuation or a $ sign followed by a-z or A-Z or 0-9. Then I used regexp to find indices in the string that match the pattern and regmatches retreives such indices.

Comment: Edited the solution.

Comment: thank you, that is really smart; but if you have time, i would still like to know why my three line solution didn't work as i intended it to?

Comment: I'm going to try. First off though, as I've spent quite some time already trying to help you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: just did thank you; please advise on anything bout my solution if you can thanks

Comment: what is ['$-] btw?

Comment: Okay, so a few comments: `['$-] `is a character class containing and thus allowing for `'`, `$`, and `-`. Note that *if inside a character class*, `$`need not be escaped. If, however, as in your code, **not** in a character class, it does require escaping (by `\\$`). I've had a look at your code; it seems you can put it in a much more succint way, namely `"\\w*([[:punct:]]|\\$)+\\w+"`, the only **conceptual** changes being `\\$` and `\\w` instead of `[a-z]|[A-Z]` (`\\w` matches letters and digits (and the underscore)).